# Does monero have a dedicated marketing team or continuous marketing contributors?

Tags: monero-community

Marketing is everything these days as we all know, It allows worse products to do better than great products, gets the product to stick in our head or create a favorable image in our heads. Is there dedicated personnel in the XMR team or contributors who try every day on a continual basis to get XMR more widely known to the public. And most importantly in Asia as this seems to be what everyone is talking about now days?

Comment: [Related](https://forum.getmonero.org/22/completed-tasks/86971/what-is-monero-is-produced-and-open-sourced-the-explanation-video-series-is-on-its-way)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not yet. However, we have probably the best community in cryptocurrencies, what you can see on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/), the [official forum](https://forum.getmonero.org/) or here at Stack Exchange.

In my opinion, marketing makes only sense after we have a GUI, so the average user can test Monero and compare to other coins.

So join the community and spread the word about the most advanced cryptocurrency out there!

Comment: It definitely appears that way. I am hoping to do work directly for Monero in the future. Perhaps it has already begun :) I keep seeing other major cryptos hiring marketing teams so i feel in the future in a community funded way this needs to become a priority. The product is absolutely great though and imo could overtake Bitcoin. I believe bitcoin has done so well because people only know of it and no other crypto. EG Ghana. The recent price rise has given us publicity but now is the time to push it

Answer (score 5):

There's no marketing team, other than the getmonero.org site. Though they have worked hard to brand and identify what needs to be done to attract new users as well as reach out to the media, especially on privacy related topics. these guys are not paid to do this though, they are simply volunteers that have a passion for cryptocurrency and genuine privacy.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe a marketing team is needed. True, marketing can make even the worst products seem appealing, but once word gets around about how terrible that product is, it will fall on its face. Look at how far Monero has come with essentially no marketing. The current popularity is based solely on the merits of the technology, which is really saying something. I think the better focus for the team members and the funding efforts is to continue to improve the technology. While growth may be slower this way, it will be inevitable as people realize that there is only one reason that Monero is one of the highest market cap coins, and it is not because of shiny advertising.

Comment: Somehow true, but there remains a risk, that a worse product with better marketing will take the market and users won't switch just because the other product is enough for them.

Comment: The use of marketing is not to let bad solutions look good. It can be used to spread the message to new circles, to correct false information, to show how the solution can be of use to people, etc.